# Discriminant of $4g+h^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we have two polynomials $g,h\in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg g = 2k+1 =:n$ and $\deg h=k$. As an example, take $g=x^7+2x^6+x+2$, $h=x^3+x+7$.

My question is:

> Why does the discriminant of $f:=4g+h^2$ always contain the factor $2^{2n-2}$ or in the example: $2^{12}$?

Up to this point, I can tell that $2$ divides $f'$, and thus, the discriminant must contain $2^{n-1}$, but where does the rest come from?

An extra question is: What is the maximal power of $2$ in $\operatorname{disc}(f)$?

Comment: There is an expression for the discriminant of a polynomial $f$ in terms of the resultant of $f$ and $f'$. Maybe that, together with standard facts about resultants, would be of some help.

Comment: I know, you can also use this one:

In terms of the roots, the discriminant is equal to

    $$a_n^{2n-2}\prod_{i<j}{(r_i-r_j)^2} $$

Okay, now in which field do the roots live and how do they match to result in a factor $2^{12}$?

Comment: I don't know. But the point of the resultant is that it can be expressed in terms of the coefficients of the polynomials; you don't need to know what or where the roots are.

Comment: $$\left[\begin{matrix} & a_n & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \ldots & a_1 & a_0 & 0 \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\ & 0 & a_n & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \ldots & a_1 & a_0 & 0 \ldots & 0 \\ & \vdots\ &&&&&&&&\vdots\\ & 0 & \ldots\ & 0 & a_n & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \ldots & a_1 & a_0 \\ & na_n & (n-1)a_{n-1} & (n-2)a_{n-2} & \ldots\ & a_1 & 0 & \ldots &\ldots & 0 \\ & 0 & na_n & (n-1)a_{n-1} & (n-2)a_{n-2} & \ldots\ & a_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ & \vdots\ &&&&&&&&\vdots\\ & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & na_n & (n-1)a_{n-1} & (n-2)a_{n-2}& \ldots\ & a_1 \\\end{matrix}\right].$$